# Book containing the following line

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, math-history, etale-cohomology

I came across the image below on social network and I feel quite excited about the line. I wonder if anyone knows what is the book (maybe a paper or an introductory note)? To the best of my knowledge, I do not think it comes from a book on étale cohomology; at least not among the well-known ones like Milne, Leifu, Freitag, Tamme, etc.

[image]

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, yes, it is likely that Grothendieck would disagree with that. But this reminds me a quote of Grothendieck about the 0 cipher. I would say that math (at least algebraic geometry) before him is not really rigirous and he is like a second Galois in the field, without him, it is like a rickshaw stuck in the mud. From my experience, I would stand by Scholze's side (author of the line), Grothendieck's style shapes the way of thinking. I would have studied something else if I hadn't known him.

Comment: Not offend, you know it. Like Harris once confessed that his mind is not beyond classical AG by italian school, I or even no one could deny the old work, but I personally think that it's only after Grothendieck, AG has a solid foundation.

Comment: Sure, FAC for instance.

Comment: Cartier said that he learned algebraic geometry from Weil, then relearned the subject after Serre, and until the field had been completely transformed again by Grothendieck. You are seemingly trying to accuse me for dishonoring those predecessors. It is not what I mean, their work set a ground for successors like Grothendieck but it does not mean they completely changed the field, not to say the way of thinking.

Comment: I am not *accusing* you of anything. If anything, I was assuming I could have an adult conversation, sigh.

Answer (score 2):

This is from the preface of "Lectures grothendieckiennes" by Frédéric Jaëck et al. The preface (and in particular this footnote) is written by Peter Scholze. You can read the book online for free (at time of writing) at https://spartacus-idh.com/094.html

Comment: Many thanks, I just remembered that I read a comment saying that it is Scholze's words; but even so, I could not find it.